# How to use DocumentSnapshot instead of QuerySnapshot?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have QuerySnapshot method that gets some data from firebase:

```
  getBookings(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
return snapshot.data.docs
    .map((doc) => CalendarBookingBlock(
          bookingName: doc.data()['bookingName'],
          bookingTime: doc.data()['bookingData'],
        ))
    .toList();
}
```

But I have to use DocumentSnapshot. When I tried it `snapshot.data.docs` wasn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) represents a single document.  It doesn't contain other documents like a [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html).  There are examples of querying individual documents in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read).  Typically it goes like this:

```
if (snapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
    // document fields are in data
}
else {
    // decide what you want to do if the document doesn't exist
}
```